# c# Column 'PlanTime' does not belong to table SessionMessage

Tags: c#

This is my code

```
 DataSet dataSet = s.GetSessionAvailability("RES", Convert.ToDateTime(todayDate), 3, 1, 1);
            string response = "";
            foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {

                    response += "ID="+row["ID"]+" ";
                    response += "PlanTime="+ row["PlanTime"]+" ";
                    response += "Available" + row["Available"] + " ";
                    response += "ReturnTime" + row["ReturnTime"] + " ";

                    response += "<br/>";
                }
            }
            Response.Write(response);
```

I got this exception:

```
Column 'PlanTime' does not belong to table SessionMessage.
```

I am sure the `PlanTime` column is exist.

#### I tried to get the column names like this

```
DataSet dataSet = s.GetSessionAvailability("RES", Convert.ToDateTime(todayDate), 3, 1, 1);
            string response = "";
            DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0].Clone();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                response += col.ColumnName+"<br/>";
            }
            Response.Write(response);
```

#### And yes the PlanTime is exist

why is that exception please?

Comment: Are you sure it also exists in the table SessionMessage? With the same spelling and not Plantime or something. You seem to only check the first table.

Comment: @David you have a good idea. The documentation that I got states that I have two tables, which are `Availability` and `SessionMessage` what should I do take just the availability table please?

Comment: Ok. So that solved the problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check only checks the first table. The SessionMessage table may not have a PlanTime column.

Answer (score 0):

it also exists in the table SessionMessage.

Comment: How did you know that?